# How to confirm USB drive partitioned correctly?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, partitioning, filesystems

A few years ago, I partitioned an external USB drive and installed an EXT3 filesystem on it. The filesystem has 4 terabytes of space.

Recently, I realized the drive itself is only a 3 terabyte drive.

Obviously, I've lost/overwritten some data and need to repartition the drive, but, when I do, how can I make sure I've partitioned it correctly? What I've come up with so far:

- Fill up the drive with psuedo-random data (eg, thousands of 100M files) and keep track of the sha1 hashes of those drives. Then, compute the sha1 hashes of the files on the drive to confirm they match. I've used this to test USB flash drives sold on eBay as having "32G" worth of space when they only have 4GB, but this seems tedious for a multi-terabyte drive.
- Is there a Linux tool for "write to various random spots on this file system instead of using the normal 'sequential' method of using blocks"? Or any sort of tool that can test I've partitioned my drive correctly?

Comment: In order to check your partition for errors, run `e2fsck`/`fsck` (File System ChecK). See `man fsck`. (Filling the drive with pseudo data seems absurd) (This seems like more of a Stack Exchange Linux/Unix question)

Comment: @Krii What if partitioning is the ONLY error on the drive? Will fsck really report that? For my current 4TB-really-3TB drive, fsck yields no errors.